# Как сделать снимок экрана (скриншот) в Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, скриншот

Хотелось бы реализовать следующее: нажимаю на кнопочку - она мне делает снимок экрана в формате .jpg и сохраняет на диск С. Опишите, пожалуйста, поподробнее, как это сделать?

Comment: Тут есть 2 варианта: использовать буфер обмена или получить доступ к экрану и скопировать его содержимое в Image (или Bitmap), а потом сохранить. Я так полагаю, что этот вопрос связан с предыдущим. Сейчас пороюсь в старых исходниках: где-то у меня что-то подобное было.

Comment: все я сделал :) вопросик не совсем по вопросу - а как реализовать, чтобы если свернул приложение оно ушло не в низ а где таймер иконкой? :)

Comment: Для сворачивания программы в трей можно компонент скачать. Он, насколько я помню, есть в версиях Delphi, начиная с 2005-ой, на закладке Additional, TTrayIcon. Как им пользоваться, можно почитать в книге М. Е. Флёнова - "Библия Delphi".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На C++ WinAPI:

```
HBITMAP bitmap;

int width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
int height= GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
HWND handle = GetDesktopWindow();
HDC desktopDC = GetDC(handle);
HDC captureDC = CreateCompatibleDC(desktopDC);

bitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(desktopDC, width, height);
SelectObject(captureDC, bitmap); 
BitBlt(captureDC, 0, 0, width, height, desktopDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY|CAPTUREBLT); 
SaveCapturedBitmap(bitmap);

ReleaseDC(handle, desktopDC);
DeleteDC(captureDC);
```

В итоге bitmap хранит снимок экрана (после использования не забыть `DeleteObject(bitmap)`).